# How to pass deterministic variables and observtions to pymc.Metropolis()

Tags: pymc3, inference, pymc, model-fitting

I am trying to recreate this tutorial by Austin Rochford about Non-parametric bayesian models from 2016 which can be found [here](https://austinrochford.com/posts/2016-02-25-density-estimation-dpm.html).

The tutorial uses pymc3 and theano which are no longer supported and there is no environment with package versions specified. When I try and run the model:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    alpha = pm.Gamma('alpha', 1., 1.)
    beta = pm.Beta('beta', 1., alpha, shape=K)
    w = pm.Deterministic('w', beta * T.concatenate([[1], T.extra_ops.cumprod(1 - beta)[:-1]]))
    component = pm.Categorical('component', w, shape=N)

    tau = pm.Gamma('tau', 1., 1., shape=K)
    lambda_ = pm.Uniform('lambda', 0, 5, shape=K)
    mu = pm.Normal('mu', 0, lambda_ * tau, shape=K)
    obs = pm.Normal('obs', mu[component], lambda_[component] * tau[component],
                    observed=old_faithful_df.std_waiting.values)
with model:
    step1 = pm.Metropolis(vars=[alpha, beta, w, lambda_, tau, mu, obs])
    step2 = pm.ElemwiseCategoricalStep([component], np.arange(K))
    
    trace_ = pm.sample(20000, [step1, step2])


trace = trace_[10000::10]
```

I get the following errors:

```
The following variables are not random variables in the model: ['w','obs]
```

They obviously aren't random variables, implying the call signature for pm.Metropolis has changes from pymc3 to pymc5.

I removed these from the vars list and then had the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pymc' has no attribute 'ElemwiseCategoricalStep'
```

I do not really know anything about either pymc3 or pymc5. I have tried rummaging in their documentation to no avail. Does anyone know how I can rewrite this model and inference so that I can run it with pymc5?

thank you!